# Cocoa: How to create CFUrl/NSUrl for reading from a memory buffer for ExtAudioFileOpenURL

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, url, buffer

Some functions, like ExtAudioFileOpenURL, only accept URLs to as a path to a file.  This is fine but what if your file is within a container or a memory buffer, is it still possible to create a URL to point to this?

eg

```
char * w = read_sample_bytes(...);
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateForBuffer(..., w, ...);
ExtAudioFileOpenURL(url, &extAudioFile);
etc..
```

or will I have to extract the data to a temporary file and create a url to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you would first create an `AudioFileID` with `AudioFileInitializeWithCallbacks`, then wrap the result using `ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID` for the `ExtAudioFile` APIs you will need. No CF/NS-URL is required to create/read files in memory using this approach.

Comment: I think this is the correct approach for reading from a memory buffer.  As it turned out, for me, it was better to stream the file data so I ended up using a combination of AudioToolbox's AudioFileStream and AudioConverter - skipping ExtAudioFile completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a URL to a region of memory.

For your specific purpose, you'll have to either do what Justin suggested or use [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/).